# Losing stylesheet setup after applying font change

Tags: c++, css, qt

In my code I have widgets and change their styles the following way:

```
resultGroupBox->setStyleSheet("background-color:#7979ec;");
```

And later in code:

```
 resultGroupBox->setStyleSheet("font: bold 14px\"Verdana\"");//this is done by function (set_fonts());
```

After the second style is applied the first is lost. I wonder if there is a way to deal with this (I need the both the fonts and the background), except for setting background-color and fonts in the same command.

Comment: You can get the stylesheet with `resultGroupBox->styleSheet();`. Use that to get the existing style sheet, and append the font to it. You're also missing `;` at the end of the second style sheet.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your function is "**set**StyleSheet", isn't there a function to "**Add**Style"?

Even better is adding a class instead of a style. For example with the jQuery addClass function. See https://api.jquery.com/addclass/